# Resize screenshot in A-frame

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

I have a scene with A-frame and I am using the method `getCanvas` to get a screenshot and send it to PHP. Is there any way to resize the getCanvas image size? Because the default one is 4096x2048 and I need it smaller. If i change the default dimensions in the source code it resizes badly, with stretching.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot component's schema allows you to set the desired width and height, so you could try something like this - where you set the attribute first, then call getCanvas:

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/a-frame-screenshot-size

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('snap-on-space-key', {
  init: function () {
    const scene = this.el
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
      const SPACEKEY = 32
      if (event.which === SPACEKEY) {
        scene.setAttribute('screenshot', {
          width: 1024,
          height: 512
        })
        const canvas = scene.components.screenshot.getCanvas('equirectangular');
        console.log(canvas)
        scene.components.screenshot.capture('equirectangular')
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Alternatively you could also set it once on the scene:

`<a-scene screenshot="width: 1024; height: 512;">...`

Comment: The problem is that is resizes weird, I squishes the image. It works, but very poorly. I am trying to get a perspective screenshot, do you think that affects it?

Comment: Tried this on Chrome - set the getCanvas argument to 'perspective': https://glitch.com/edit/#!/a-frame-perspective-sn is it any better for you?

Comment: Another thing to note (from my obeservation), is that the actual browser window size appears to make a difference. So if you resize your browser to those dimensions you'll likely get a better result.